# No Network access with Fedora Core 8

Tags: linux, fedora, networking

I have recently taken over for another system admin on a project and am in the process of figuring out what we have on our servers before rebuilding things the way they need to be.  I have one Dell server running Fedora Core 8.  I am unable to connect to the network at all.

I am plugged into a known good port, I have tried dhcp and manual set IP configurations. The dhcp will not receive a lease. After both methods I am not even able to ping my gateway. I have diabled all the firewalls to make sure those are not the issue. Here is my ifconfig.

```
eth0   Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:1C:23:E2:FC:56
       UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MYU:1500 Metric:1
       RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
       RX bytes:0 (0.0b) TX bytes:0 (0.0b)
       Interrupt:16
```

This is configured with dhcp just after doing a dhclient eth0 and it returns no working leases.

What else should I check?

Comment: sorry to ask but have you tried rebooting the server?  I've gone through a similar issue were I would assign a static but the dhcp lease would end up coming back.

Comment: I tried that also

Comment: Does it have a link on eth0? What does `ethtool eth0` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'd run an:

```
ifconfig -a
route -v
```

Check dmesg and logs for related info. Check the ethernet card itself. Is the other Sysadmin available? Did he leave under less than amicable circumstances?

You mention firewalls was the server running iptables?

Comment: The firewall was running iptables, and the last sysadmin was not so much a sysadmin, as one of the windows servers he ran had a virus.

I will get to the servers today and post the output of the commands you guys told me to run.

Comment: Thanks everyone, after examining dmesg after trying to bring each interface up I realize that what was believed to be eth0 was eth1, so now things are running on eth1